# Hosting Web API in a Windows Service - Combined or Separate

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, service, windows-services, owin

I want to self host a Web API in a windows service, but should I keep my Web API separate or should it be done within the windows service. I am pretty sure it can be done both ways based on [this example](https://github.com/danesparza/OWIN-WebAPI-Service).

What will the downsides be if I combine them.

Comment: you need your web api's reference anyways in the windows service , if they are together its easy for you. Otherwise you have to reference the assemblies of web api somehow, I would say keeping them together.

Comment: I decided to keep everything together because I saw that you need to do a hack to reference the assemblies if separate.

Comment: why is better self host a Web API? not in IIS hosting ? Anyways, Windows Service can reference assemblies (is NET), not problem.